# Is there an order of difficulty for MSA?

Tags: grammar, language-acquisition, arabic

Has an order of grammatical difficulty for Modern Standard Arabic been discovered (or proposed) similar to that found for L2 learners of English?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in more detail?  A bit more information about "an order of grammatical difficulty" might help people understand your question.

Comment: Some research has identified an order of grammatical difficulty for L2 learners of English: learners appear to learn grammatical constructs in a relatively invariable order, regardless of which language they speak as L1.  The differences between L1 and English have a greater influence on the time it takes to proceed through the order, rather than change the order itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to [Order of acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_acquisition) - the idea that there is a fixed order in which learners acquire different aspects of grammar.

There's one article in this [journal](http://org.uib.no/smi/nsm/meec.html); an unedited version can be found [here](http://org.uib.no/smi/paj/Nielsen.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think there is not, each Arabic country have it's own program of learning, most likely that this programs gonna be close to each others but there is no unified program of progression nor an unified certificate. i am not 100% certain, so i might be wrong.